# A possible type conversion mistake when creating FMod binding. What could be wrong?

Tags: go, fmod, cgo

I'm attempting to create a Go binding for the low level API of FMod Studio via Go and CGo. My package seems to compile, however the example program using it complains that the parameter I passed to one of the FMod functions is invalid. The two used FMod functions from fmod.h:

```
FMOD_RESULT F_API FMOD_System_Create               (FMOD_SYSTEM **system);
FMOD_RESULT F_API FMOD_System_GetVersion                (FMOD_SYSTEM *system, unsigned int *version);
```

This is possibly a type conversion, however I'm relatively new to Go and not quite sure what's wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Here's the FMod package:

```
package fmod

// #cgo darwin  LDFLAGS: -framework fmod
// #cgo linux   LDFLAGS: -lfmod -ldl
// #cgo windows LDFLAGS: -lfmod
// #include "fmod.h"
// #include "fmod_errors.h"
import "C"

var fmod *C.FMOD_SYSTEM

func Init() {
    var version *C.uint
    res := C.FMOD_System_Create(&fmod)
    errCheck(res, "System_Create")
    res = C.FMOD_System_GetVersion(fmod, version)
    errCheck(res, "version")
    println(C.GoString(C.FMOD_ErrorString(res)))
}

func errCheck(result C.FMOD_RESULT, msg string) {
    if result != C.FMOD_OK {
        println("Audio Error: "+msg)
    }
}
```

The test program:

```
package main
import("fmod")

func main() {
    fmod.Init()
}
```

Comment: Whats the text of the error?

Comment: What happens if you initialize version to some value rather than just declaring it?  does that help?